# Subqueries in Hive - Getting an error "only subquery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed"

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hql

Trying to run this query in Hive with a subquery that goes as follows:

```
select y,m,d,h from A
where d not in (select d from B)
```

I get an error that `"only subquery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed"`

Anybody have any ideas what this means and how to get around it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of hive are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using a hive version < 0.13. Some subquery expressions aren't allowed, and that is one of them. Try this left outer join instead:

```
SELECT A.y, A.m, A.d, A.h
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.d = B.d
WHERE B.d IS NULL;
```

If you move to hive 0.13, you should be able to use it this way:

```
SELECT A.y, A.m, A.d, A.h FROM A WHERE A.d NOT IN (SELECT d FROM B);
```

Comment: Left semi join would be the equivalent of in, the op wants "not in"